# Incomplete sentence without linking verbs

Tags: grammar

The cat [was] sitting by the stairs.

Why is this sentence incomplete without the verb was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The cat sitting by the stairs.

This is a noun phrase, not a complete sentence. (What about the cat?)

Although specifically different, it has the same general construction as the following:

> The red apple.

(What about the red apple?)

*Sitting by the stairs* is being used to qualify the noun, but there is no verb (or predicate) for the sentence itself:

> The cat ***was*** sitting by the stairs.
>   The cat sitting by the stairs ***had four legs.***
>   The cat sitting by the stairs ***purred.***

Or:

> I ***ate*** the red apple.
>   The red apple ***rolled down the hill***.

---

If nothing more is added to the noun phrase, then the following type of dialogue might occur:

> "The cat sitting by the stairs."
>   "Yes? What about it?"

In short, it's incomplete because it's an unfinished thought.

---

You can have a noun phrase as complex as you want, but the sentence itself still needs a verb to make it complete:

> The <sup>[cat sitting by the stairs, cleaning itself and meowing in hunger]</sup> ***was black***.

Answer (score 1):

The progressive tense "**sitting**" requires a conjugation of "**to be**" as an auxiliary/helping verb. Without the helping verb, there's no way to convey when the continuous action occurred.

This holds true for all forms of the continuous/progressive tense.

Present progressive:

> The cat *is* sitting by the stairs.

Past progressive:

> The cat *was* sitting by the stairs.

Future progressive:

> The cat *will be* sitting by the stairs.